# bootstrap-vue b-modal doesn't removed from body

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

```
<template>
   <Form ... >
       <b-modal .....>
...
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form } from 'vee-validate';
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component';

@Options({})
export class MyModal extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

code is over here

[image]

and contents from dev tools are here

as you can see, i didn't open modal yet(except first one) but modal attached already....
so i just curious what can i do for remove this modals at initial state...
is there any guide for this situations?

Answer (score 0):

This should should work just fine

```html
<template>
  <b-modal v-if="showModal">
    ...
  </b-modal>
</template>
```

If it doesn't work, I guess that Bootstrap is doing it's own thing and that you could either pass on that component or try to hack that one in an ugly way by adding even more JS to it.